# Only show header data but not show details data on dataset (crystal report c#)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I want to show crystal report on dât but it's only show header without show details data

I use dataset to show data but it's not show details data

I created dataset and link to crystal report... 
It worked when I tried it at Main Report Preview

Please see images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZYEE.png

```
 crpQLVT rpt = new crpQLVT();
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-FFIKNAO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=QLVT;Integrated Security=True";);
 conn.Open();
 SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from ThanhPhan", conn);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 dap.Fill(ds);
 rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
 crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
```

and result https://i.stack.imgur.com/NShUN.png

Please help me fix it !
Thanks for help !

Comment: did u checked whether data comes to your data adapter or not?

Comment: i checked and it doesn't have data.... but I can't understand why it doesn't have

Comment: means you don't get data from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check if `connectionString` is valid and point to database that you want.

2) You have to refresh your crystal report viewer after assigning report source to it like

```
crpQLVT rpt = new crpQLVT();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-FFIKNAO\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=QLVT;Integrated Security=True";);
con.Close();  //close if existing connection open
con.Open();
string cmdText = "Select * from ThanhPhan";
cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(dr);

rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
con.Close();
```

Comment: it's still not working, I checked connection it's ok... but I understand why it doesn't get data from database

Comment: please try with updated solution and first tell me whether you get data from database or not in `dt.Load(dr);` line

Comment: Welcome and glad to hear you have get rid from your problem. and vote up also to answer :)